# Preserve null strings when assigning to .Value with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

(edit: added 2 more restrictions to solutions)

I have a table (listobject wise) in which I need to duplicate certain rows.  I'm using SourceListRow.Range.Value2 = DestListRow.Range.Value2 for efficiency reasons (copying whole ranges in one go).  All formula columns after the copied cell ranges auto-expand perfectly into the new rows and act upon the copied data.  I'm using Excel 2010 here on Windows.

However, although I've already been using this sort of code for eons, I've only now stumbled upon an oddity when using Range.Value / Range.Value2: if you assign an empty string to it, the final cell value will not be an empty string, but it will be Empty.  That is: the data isn't copied over faithfully, and the copy can differ from the source, especially if consecutive formulas use ISBLANK etc. on it.  Therefore the same formula will have different results when working on the copy vs. the source.

See below test code.  Open a new, blank, Excel workbook, go to VBA, add a new module and add the following code:

```
Sub Test()
  ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Formula = "="""""
  ActiveSheet.Range("b1").Formula = "=isblank(a1)"
  ActiveSheet.Range("c1").Value2 = TypeName(ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Value2)

  ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Value2 = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Value2
  ActiveSheet.Range("b2").Formula = "=isblank(a2)"
  ActiveSheet.Range("c2").Value2 = TypeName(ActiveSheet.Range("a2").Value2)

  ActiveSheet.Range("a3").Value2 = ""
  ActiveSheet.Range("b3").Formula = "=isblank(a3)"
  ActiveSheet.Range("c3").Value2 = TypeName(ActiveSheet.Range("a3").Value2)

  ActiveSheet.Range("a4").Formula = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Formula
  ActiveSheet.Range("b4").Formula = "=isblank(a4)"
  ActiveSheet.Range("c4").Value2 = TypeName(ActiveSheet.Range("a4").Value2)

  Call ActiveSheet.Range("a1").Copy
  Call ActiveSheet.Range("a5").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
  ActiveSheet.Range("b5").Formula = "=isblank(a5)"
  ActiveSheet.Range("c5").Value2 = TypeName(ActiveSheet.Range("a5").Value2)
End Sub
```

Then run it and look at the sheet;

- B1 tells FALSE (as it should - the cell is not empty), and C1 tells "String" (the cell value is indeed an empty string);
- B2 tells TRUE, even though we just copied over A1's value as-is; C2 tells "Empty", while it should tell "String" if the value was copied over faithfully;
- as a test, B3 tells TRUE, even though we just set it explicitly to an empty string; C3 again tells "Empty" to confirm the data mangling;
- assigning Range.Formula to OtherRange.Formula works (the String data type is preserved in B4), but I do not want to copy formula's, I want to copy only the values!
- as a test I mimic what the GUI would yield in A5, and sure enough, Copy/Paste-As-Values does preserve the is-an-empty-string state...

What to do?

- using Range.Copy / Range.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues) is unacceptable, performance-wise and clipboard-wise;
- using .Formula is also not an option, because I want to copy the values;
- I could iterate over all values in the array, testing if they're a null string and then setting those cell's formula to ="", but I want to copy whole multi-cell ranges in one go to gain efficiency here...
- I can't use autofilters and such because my data lives in a table (a.k.a. ListObject); I could use the table's own autofilter, but people may have it in use already so I'd have to restore it afterwards which is too much of a kludge.
- using Range.Find and Range.Replace is not an option either, since that changes the user's Find/Replace dialog settings.

All ideas appreciated!

Comment: If you use the [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTBLANK-function-6a92d772-675c-4bee-b346-24af6bd3ac22), it treats truly blank cells and cells that contain a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) the same. e.g. `=not(countblank(a5))` to receive a TRUE/FALSE that mimics `=isblank(a5)`..

Comment: You can also use [ISEMPTY Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isempty.php) to check for blank cells or ranges.

Comment: Problem is, I handle the VBA side of things, and the users should be able to use whichever functions they want in the table.  There shouldn't be the need to add a disclaimer that ISBLANK is not permitted in this special case... (I should be glad if the users can manage to write a formula in the first place :) )  I.e.: it should be 100% fool-proof.

Comment: Given that the performance difference between Value and Value2 isn't spectacular, why not use .Value?

Comment: @jkpieterse: unfortunately, .Value behaves identical to .Value2 in this case (the diff is more in extended data type handling like Date and Currency)

Comment: It seems that the only way you can provide conformity to the user is to make them all zero-length strings or all truly blank. Pick one (sounds like the latter is better) and make the adjustments.

Comment: @Jeeped: point is the source rows I copy from can be anything the user can dream up, like e.g. truly blank cells or formulas returning ="", or mixes of these.  I could inspect all 'empty' cells and set them to either one according to the source's cell value, but that negates quite a big chunk of the efficiency if there's lots of these empty cells...

Comment: If the source has either `""` or truly blanks then that should be fixed or the users should be banned from using ISBLANK in favor of NOT(COUNTBLANK)). Either they want to determine the lack of any substantial value or not. btw, `NOT(LEN(a5)) does the same thing and may make more sense to them.

Comment: @Jeeped: problem is I have no control over the users' behavior - I provide a generic Excel solution which is expected to 'just work' when the average Excel user is thrown at it.  Which maybe is in itself a pretty shitty situation in hindsight, given Excel's idiosyncrasies and ease of abuse :(

Comment: Remember Carl, as soon as you make something idiot proof, the world just builds a better idiot.

Comment: @Jeeped: being a perfectionist I need to remember that quote more often :)  For now I think I'll just opt for a less performant but more idiot proof design.

Answer (score 0):

SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlank) and AutoFilter treat null strings differently. Is your source data filterable? If so, could you use a placeholder value and then change the cells to have `.Formula = "="""""` after copying?

I took your sample code and generated the workbook, then added a row above it for a filter header. The below code would change all null strings to "ChangeMe"; you could then copy over the values and replace all instances of "ChangeMe" in your destination with "=""""" using Range.Replace.

```
Sub Test2()

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.Color = 255 'Just to prove that xlCellTypeBlanks only selects actual blanks

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" 'Shows both actual blanks and ZLS/null strings
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Be able to use SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) to reference all ZLS
ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2 = "ChangeMe"
'Now unfilter and unhide your data, copy using .Value2, then .Replace "ChangeMe" with "="""""

End Sub
```

I think that accomplishes what you are trying to do - let me know if this is the right direction for a solution.

*Edit: misinterpreted original question. Below old answer is incorrect.*

While not quite as efficient as your original code, using .AutoFilter is much more efficient than looping through many cells. Furthermore, .AutoFilter treats zero-length strings and empty cells the same.

Something like this:

```
Sub CopyAndClearFakeBlanks()

Dim WSSource As Worksheet
Dim WSDest As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long
Dim LPasteRow As Long

Set WSSource = Sheets("Source Data")
Set WSDest = Sheets("Paste Here")

LRow = WSSource.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'Note that this will ignore blanks, so you may want to use a different method for finding your last row. Depends on how your users would need the data if there are trailing blanks.

On Error Resume Next
LPasteRow = 2 'Always need at least one row before the data for filtering properly; you can delete after if necessary
LPasteRow = WSDest.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
WSDest.AutoFilterMode = False
On Error GoTo 0 'ofc use proper error handling in your actual code

WSDest.Range("A" & LPasteRow & ":A" & LPasteRow + LRow - 1).Value2 = WSSource.Range("A1:A" & LRow).Value2
WSDest.Range("A" & LPasteRow - 1 & ":A" & LPasteRow + LRow).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=" 'Show blank or ZLS only

On Error Resume Next
WSDest.Range("A" & LPasteRow & ":A" & LPasteRow + LRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear 'Turn them into true blanks
WSDest.ShowAllData
WSDest.AutoFilterMode = False
On Error GoTo 0

Set WSDest = Nothing
Set WSSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: By setting Range.Value2 the data is copied identically to my code, so it doesn't address the fact that null-string cells aren't copied over correctly.  Clearing all copied 'empty' cells afterwards is not what I want, since they are already Empty, which is what I want to avoid (I want to keep the empty-string and truly empty distinction).  The source data contains both types of empty (some empty strings even come from formulas), so I can't set those to Empty either.  All these cells also live in a table/ListObject; applying an autofilter to the pasted range is not an option either.

Comment: As a side-note to your comment about the efficiency: I already use `DestRange.Value2 = SourceRange.Value2`.  By putting SourceRange.Value2 into a variant first and inspecting that array for blanks you get almost no performance loss for inspecting individual cells either.  It's more that I do not want to have to perform this inspection & correction afterwards at all.  All in all: close, but no cigar ;)

Comment: Sorry about that @CarlColijn - I misinterpreted your post to mean you have the opposite problem. What does your source data look like - it is filterable? See my edit for a proposal that may work; seems to be good on my test data.

Comment: I capture the data from SourceRange.Value in an array, then process it before assigning it back to the DestRange.Value.  Using .SpecialCells to get the candidates, replace them with placeholders and using .Replace afterwards are in my case unnecessary actions - I haven't performance-tested your solution vs. mine, but I already have the data pass under my fingers in my processing loop (on the array).  Building a union of all null-string cells to set afterwards is thus no real effort in itself, it's just that I wanted to avoid any workarounds in the first place.

Comment: And I can't use an autofilter either, since I work inside a table (could use the table's own autofilter and restore it afterwards if already in use, but that's just another klude I want to avoid).  Thanks for thinking out of the box though, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would just create an array variant and assign it to the range you want to copy, then assign the range you want to paste to as the array.

In the example below, I have created tables and copied the whole databodyrange but the same idea applies to rows etc. Let me know if further explanation is required.

```
''' Define Objects and Variables
Dim table1 As ListObject: Set table1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
Dim table2 As ListObject: Set table2 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table2")
Dim tableArray() As Variant


''' Assign range data to array
tableArray = table1.DataBodyRange.Value


''' Output array values to range
table2.DataBodyRange = tableArray
```